# Which database is secure for web application for avoiding hacking

Tags: database

Which database is secure for web application for avoiding hacking

Comment: by asking this question I am assuming you are not an experienced developer or programmer which then suggests you should ask a possible provider, like a hosting company or web development firm rather than a forum like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guarantee that any software can be made immune from hacking.  All databases can be made to work if secured properly; all of them are vulnerable if not.  No one can say that database X is always secure.

Answer (score 1):

They're mostly all secure (though you can subscribe to any vulnerability announcement mailing lists... so if a major security flaw shows up in the next few years, you will have time to react).

Security issues are mostly design flaws, for example SQL injection, unescaped content that you print out directly onto your webpage, etc.

To learn some of the basics of web design security, you may wish to do all the tutorials on http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/